# How do I Delete related resources with TastyPie

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I have two related resources:

```
class QuantityResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Quantity.objects.all()

class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    quantities = fields.ToManyField(QuantityResource, 'quantities', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
```

If I PUT to an existing entry with `quantities: []` I expect TastyPie to delete all related Quantity objects, but this is not happening. Similarly if I put a list to quantities that does not include an existing value, I'd expect it to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tastypie doesn't support deleting objects through a many-to-many relationship. Only update and add are supported. [Relevant code](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L2361-L2366). It will [call clear](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L2333-L2338) on the related manager for your many-to-many field but that will only disassociate your related models from the parent it won't actually delete them. There was a [patch](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/216) 2 years ago to add the functionality but it wasn't ever merged.

The best way to handle this is probably to enable filtering on the `QuantityResrouce` and `PUT` the updated list to the quantity resource filtered by the parent resource which will add/update/delete everything in the collection. Note that you'll have to add a `ForeignKey` field to the `QuantityResource` otherwise you won't be able to save the collection due to database constraints (assuming your `entry` field is required on the `Quantity` model.

```
class QuantityResource(ModelResource):

    entry = fields.ForeignKey('your.resources.EntryResource', 'entry')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Quantity.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'entry': ['exact'],
        }
```

Here's a test case to illustrate what I mean:

```
from tastypie.test import ResourceTestCase

from testres.models import Quantity, Entry


class EntryResourcesTest(ResourceTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(EntryResourcesTest, self).setUp()

        entry = Entry.objects.create(name='Foo')
        entry2 = Entry.objects.create(name='Bar')

        Quantity.objects.create(entry=entry, quantity=1)
        Quantity.objects.create(entry=entry, quantity=3)
        Quantity.objects.create(entry=entry, quantity=5)

        Quantity.objects.create(entry=entry2, quantity=2)

    def test_delete_item(self):
        objs = self.deserialize(
                self.api_client.get('/api/v1/quantity/?entry=1'))['objects'][1:]

        self.assertHttpAccepted(self.api_client.put(
            '/api/v1/quantity/?entry=1', data={ 'objects': objs }))

        # Ensure resource deleted
        obj = self.deserialize(self.api_client.get('/api/v1/entry/1/'))
        self.assertEqual(len(obj['quantities']), 2)

        # Make sure we didn't delete them all
        obj = self.deserialize(self.api_client.get('/api/v1/quantity/'))
        self.assertEqual(len(obj['objects']), 3)
```

Comment: Haven't done a PUT to a list endpoint before. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: The patch from 2 years ago seemed perfect, I just dropped that into a local subclass of ModelResource. Working like a champ!